# How to set default value of a directory path as a project setting

Tags: c#, winforms, settings, default

In a winform C# project, I added `HomeDir` as a directory path in the project settings. I want to set its initial value to `Documents` folder. This directory is not a constant string, so I can't use it in the setting dialog and also in the `Settings.Designer.cs` something like :

```
[global::System.Configuration.UserScopedSettingAttribute()]
[global::System.Diagnostics.DebuggerNonUserCodeAttribute()]
[global::System.Configuration.DefaultSettingValueAttribute(System.Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments))]
    public string HomeDir 
    {
        get 
        {
            return ((string)(this["HomeDir"]));
        }
        set 
        {
            this["HomeDir"] = value;
        }
    }
```

It will give the following error:

> Error 1   An attribute argument must be a constant expression, typeof expression or array creation expression of an attribute parameter type

Answer (score 3, accepted):

well, if `HomeDir` is not set in `Settings` (or path doesn't exist), use:

```
string docs = System.Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments);
```

to get `Documents` folder full path

Comment: Please read the update of my question, I just can use a constant for the default value

Comment: @Ahmad, i don't think you should put default value in config, because there is not good default for user `Documents`. Leave it `""` for example and before using `HomeDir` value in code, check whether it empty or exist and if no: then go for `System.Environment.GetFolderPath(...)`

Comment: Thanks, now I got what you mean! I must check if its empty.

Comment: @Ahmad, good. consider also simple check `Directory.Exists(HomeDir)`. just in case